# Can the same aura be stacked?

Tags: warframe

For example, 4 warframes have Rejuvenation aura in the same game.
This is the mod description:

> Team health regenerates +3 HEAL RATE

Will then the team get +12 HEAL RATE ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a Warframe's Aura mod effects do stack with any and all other Warframe Aura mod of the same nature. Every Aura effect is listed as being stackable by the [Aura wiki page](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Aura), although Speed Holster still needs confirmation.

Most Auras can be stacked for a maximum effect of four times the maximum rank's effect. For example, four Warframes with maxed out Rejuvenation will each receive a 12 health regeneration bonus. There are a few exceptions:

- [Corrosive Projection](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Corrosive_Projection) will max out at 100% armor reduction, even though each individual max ranked mod is 30% armor reduction and would add up to 120%.
- Stacking [Enemy Radar](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Enemy_Radar) does increase the coverage radius of the radar, but it quickly reaches the limit of the mini-map coverage.
- [Shield Disruption](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Shield_Disruption) will max out at 72% shield capacity reduction, even though each individual max ranked mod is 24% shield capacity reduction and would add up to 96%.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a wiki page stating that you can stack it: [Warframe Wikia](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Rejuvenation)

I can't currently play and test this out in game, so I can't speak to the wikia's accuracy.